# Implement Adobe Fonts in Wordpress Neve theme

Tags: css, wordpress, fonts

I'm attempting to implement an Adobe font family into the Neve theme for WP, to no avail. I followed the steps suggested by Adobe for transferring the font that I want to use and I have also installed the Adobe Fonts plugin. The font is recognised but still does not appear in any font menu for the theme.

I have also installed a custom CSS plugin and implemented the following code:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.typekit.net/ati2qpt.css">

    function add_custom_font() { 
        $font_path_ttf = get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/fonts/zuume-cut, sans-serif';
        $extra_font_path_ttf = get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/fonts/zuume-cut, sans-serif';
        ?>
        <style type="text/css">

        @font-face {
            font-family: 'zuume-cut, sans-serif';
            src: url(<?php echo esc_url($font_path_ttf); ?>)  format('truetype');
        }

        @font-face {
            font-family: 'zuume-cut, sans-serif';
            src: url(<?php echo esc_url($extra_font_path_ttf); ?>)  format('truetype');
        }

        </style>
        <?php
    }
    add_action('wp_head', 'add_custom_font');
    add_action('customize_controls_print_styles', 'add_custom_font');

    function add_custom_fonts($localized_data) {

        // First Font
        $localized_data['fonts']['Custom'][] = 'zuume-cut, sans-serif';
        // Second Font
        $localized_data['fonts']['Custom'][] = 'ExtraFontName';

        return $localized_data;
    }
    add_filter('neve_react_controls_localization', 'add_custom_fonts');
```

...this code is partly adapted from another source who asked a similar question here. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

The `$font_path_ttf` and `$extra_font_path_ttf` dont't refer to a proper font file.

Provided, you've copied valid truetype files to your themes's font directory

They should look something like this:

```
    $font_path_ttf = get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/fonts/zuumeCut.ttf';

    $extra_font_path_ttf = get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/fonts/zuumeCutExtra.ttf';
```

Besides, `font-family` property in a `@font-face` rule require only one name value:

```
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'zuume-cut';
        src: url(<?php echo esc_url($font_path_ttf); ?>)  format('truetype');
        font-weight: 400;
        font-style: normal;
    }
```

You should also specify a font weight and style to map your font files to style variants.

Since your typekit css contains woff2 files you should prefer them due to their superior file compression. So your code should look something like this:

```
    $font_path = get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/fonts/zuumeCut.woff2';


    @font-face {
        font-family: 'zuume-cut';
        src: url(<?php echo esc_url($font_path); ?>)  format('woff2');
        font-weight: 400;
        font-style: normal;
    }
```

You should also remove the css `<link>` element - otherwise you might encounter conflicts between local and remote version.